# Using both text and position within Selenium getattribute()

Tags: java, html, xpath, selenium

I'm trying to build up a framework for tests using Selenium for a website that has an ADF generated Tree. The tree ends up with the structure of

```
<table>
<tr>
 <td>
  <div>
   <span>
    <a id="AN_ID" title="Expand" onclick="return false" href="#"></a>
   </span>
   <img>
   <img>
   <span>SOME_TEXT</ span>
  </div>
 </td>
</tr>
<tr></tr>
<tr></tr>
</table>
```

What I'm hoping is to have an XPath function that can use the text to find the id of the anchor, like this:

```
selenium.getAttribute("xpath=//span[text()='"+text+"']/preceding-sibling::span[1]/child::a@id");
```

Where text is input into the function when it's called. The problem arises when the strings aren't unique. So I tried to add a position into the function, like this:

```
selenium.getAttribute("xpath=//span[text()='"+text+"']["+occurrence+"]/preceding-sibling::span[1]/child::a@id");
```

So the the function calls in both the text and the occurrence in the tree of the string. This is working to find the id of the first occurrences, but it fails to find the ids of the second occurrence of a given string.

I've also tried to use

```
[text()= "" and position()= ""]
```

but this doesn't work at all.

Each anchor generates a new table that contains all the table rows of the sub level (same structure as above), so that you end up with a new table for each sub level of the tree.

Comment: irrelevant... but something looks wrong about those two `<img>` elements...

Comment: Indeed, I guess it's just because this was stripped down of all the non-relevant info, like the img src and id. It looks all naked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the occurrence should be at the end:

```
selenium.getAttribute("xpath=(//span[text()='"+text+"']/preceding-sibling::span[1]/child::a)["+occurrence+"]@id");
```

Comment: This throws the error "com.thoughtworks.selenium.SeleniumException: Element xpath=(//span[text()='abcd']/preceding-sibling::span[1]/child::a not found" Could I presume that because of the @id it's not picking up the digit at the end? Or the xpath expression doesn't like having an open parenthesis before the // ?

Comment: I think the problem is that the @id should have actually been at the end. I updated the answer, but have not had a chance to test it.

Comment: That works perfectly, thank you so much. This has been killing me for days!

Answer (score 0):

Is this HTML structure rigid and completely impossible to change? I suggest you add an id or class to those two spans. Wouldn't that solve it all...?

Another solution would be to pick the first of the two spans with something like `//table/tr/td/div/span[1]/a`.

Comment: Unfortunately the HTML structure cannot be changed. I have to design tests around the existing structure. As well, finding the spans is fine, it's differentiating between this <tr> and a <tr> that might be further down the tree with the same SOME_TEXT value. The code given is basically what is contained within each <tr>